# JQuery Expand Table - adding additional columns

Tags: php, jquery, html-table

I'm using JExpand and allow me to expand additional rows in a table.
I'd like these expandable rows to include additional columns compared to the original table.

The code for the table I'm using is :  Example Fiddle : **http://jsfiddle.net/sB5g9/1/**

```
<body>
    <table id="results" >
        <tr>
            <th>Select</th>
            <th>Population</th>
            <th>Area</th>
            <th>Official languages</th>
            <th>Other</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><select name='mode[]' class='mode' /><option value='0:0'></option><option value='1:0'>View</option><option value='2:0'>Additional</option></select></td>
            <td>306,939,000</td>
            <td>9,826,630 km2</td>
            <td>English</td>
            <td>English</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="background-color:#FFF">  <!-- hidden -->
                    <td><b>Additional Settings</b></td>
                    <td>306,939,000</td>
                    <td>9,826,630 km2</td>
                    <td>English</td>
                    <td>English</td>
        </tr>   <!-- hidden -->
        <tr>
            <td><select name='mode[]' class='mode' /><option value='0:0'></option><option value='1:0'>View</option><option value='2:0'>Additional</option></select></td>
            <td>306,939,000</td>
            <td>9,826,630 km2</td>
            <td>English</td>
            <td>English</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="background-color:#FFF">  <!-- hidden -->
                    <td><b>Additional Settings</b></td>
                    <td>306,939,000</td>
                    <td>9,826,630 km2</td>
                    <td>English</td>
                    <td>English</td>
        </tr>   <!-- hidden -->
        <tr>
            <td><select name='mode[]' class='mode' /><option value='0:0'></option><option value='1:0'>View</option><option value='2:0'>Additional</option></select></td>
            <td>306,939,000</td>
            <td>9,826,630 km2</td>
            <td>English</td>
            <td>English</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="background-color:#FFF">  <!-- hidden -->
                    <td><b>Additional Settings</b></td>
                    <td>306,939,000</td>
                    <td>9,826,630 km2</td>
                    <td>English</td>
                    <td>English</td>
        </tr>   <!-- hidden -->

   </table>
</body>
```

What I currently have is shown below. When you select additional the row is shown and it has the same number of columns as the original table. This can bee seen in the red highlight.

What I would like is to have more columns in the expanded rows as can be seen in the yellow highlight example...

[image: Example]

Any idea how I can do this? The expandable rows may include table text fields, dropdown lists etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I had a similar requirement I used [**colspan**](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp) and [**rowspan**](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_rowspan.asp)