# Jquery show tr based on drop down

Tags: jquery, forms, select

I've been looking at this question: **[JQuery Expand Table - adding additional columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20712182/jquery-expand-table-adding-additional-columns)**

and the **FIDDLE** here:  **http://jsfiddle.net/sB5g9/1/**

This does what I want, in that it shows a new `tr` based on the dropdown selected.
However whereas the fiddle example has 2 options, View & Additional, I want 3 or 4 options.

I've tried adding new entries into the select and access them via ID but it fails to work.

If I want View, Additional, Test and Support and have Additional, test and support show different `TR's` depending on what is selected is that possible ?

UPDATE
When One option is selected the others should be hidden.

Thanks

Comment: Would you please paste the code as part of your question?

Comment: Looks like it's just checking for the number value of 1 or 2. If you want more options, instead of using the if/else for the 2 values, create a switch or just make a new change function.

Comment: And you will have to use another solution, as this one is based on odd/even rows to show/hide them, but it's basically no big deal if you use classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the example given in your jsFiddle, you can do it this way:

**HTML**

```
<table id="results">
    <tr>
        <th>Select</th>
        <th>Population</th>
        <th>Area</th>
        <th>Official languages</th>
        <th>Other</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="selector">
        <td>
            <select name='mode' class='mode'>
                <option value='0'></option>
                <option value='1'>View</option>
                <option value='2'>Additional</option>
                <option value='3'>My New Option</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>306,939,000</td>
        <td>9,826,630 km2</td>
        <td>English</td>
        <td>English</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hidden">
        <td><b>Additional Settings</b></td>
        <td>306,939,000</td>
        <td>9,826,630 km2</td>
        <td>English</td>
        <td>English</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hidden">
        <td><b>My New Option</b></td>
        <td>306,939,000</td>
        <td>9,826,630 km2</td>
        <td>English</td>
        <td>English</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="selector">
        <td>
            <select name='mode' class='mode'>
                <option value='0'></option>
                <option value='1'>View</option>
                <option value='2'>Additional</option>
                <option value='3'>My New Option</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>306,939,000</td>
        <td>9,826,630 km2</td>
        <td>English</td>
        <td>English</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hidden">
        <td><b>Additional Settings</b></td>
        <td>306,939,000</td>
        <td>9,826,630 km2</td>
        <td>English</td>
        <td>English</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hidden">
        <td><b>My New Option</b></td>
        <td>306,939,000</td>
        <td>9,826,630 km2</td>
        <td>English</td>
        <td>English</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="selector">
        <td>
            <select name='mode' class='mode'>
                <option value='0'></option>
                <option value='1'>View</option>
                <option value='2'>Additional</option>
                <option value='3'>My New Option</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>306,939,000</td>
        <td>9,826,630 km2</td>
        <td>English</td>
        <td>English</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hidden">
        <td><b>Additional Settings</b></td>
        <td>306,939,000</td>
        <td>9,826,630 km2</td>
        <td>English</td>
        <td>English</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hidden">
        <td><b>My New Option</b></td>
        <td>306,939,000</td>
        <td>9,826,630 km2</td>
        <td>English</td>
        <td>English</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
#results .hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

**Javascript (jQuery)**

```
$(function () {    
    $('.mode').change(function () {
        var opt = +$(this).val();
        var thisParent = $(this).parents("tr");        
        var thisParentPos = $('#results .selector').index(thisParent);
        var posToDisplay = opt - 2;    

        if (posToDisplay >= 0) {
            thisParent.nextAll('.hidden').eq(posToDisplay).show();
        }
    });
});
```

Note that I've added a 3rd `option` to the `select`, and you can add as many as you need.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sB5g9/6/)

[jQuery .parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)

[jQuery .index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

[jQuery .nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextall/)

[jQuery .eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Comment: Thanks for this. Only issue I have with it is when I click on any option I want the previously shown option to be hidden. Sorry if I didn't explain that !

Comment: Just change the show line to: `thisParent.nextAll('.hidden').hide().eq(posToDisplay).show();` [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/sB5g9/7/)

Comment: You could have this done yourself, as it's just a little tweak and you have the whole idea in place.

Comment: thanks, that seems to work changing between additional and my new option, but not when selecting view or the first blank entry the last selected option stays visible.

Comment: It's all about the `if` condition just before showing/hiding. You can tweak the code yourself, I'm sure.

Comment: @MelancialUK - I'm struggling to make this hide the previous entry.. Can you point me in the right direction please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the rowindex of the row for which the dropdown is selected, based on the index you can show or hide the rows accordingly.

I have made a sample with all your required values and it shows accordingly. Just apply class to rows and change the value field of the dropdowns based on the sequence of rows and it will work great.

HTML:

```
<table id="results">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Select
        </th>
        <th>
            Value
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select name='mode' class='mode'>
            <option value='1'></option>
            <option value='2'>View</option>
            <option value='3'>Additional</option>
            <option value='4'>Test</option>
            <option value='5'>Support</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            306,939,000
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="View">
        <td>
            <b>View</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            306,939,000
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Additional">
        <td>
            <b>Additional</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            306,939,000
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Test">
        <td>
            <b>Test</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            306,939,000
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Support">
        <td>
            <b>Support</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            306,939,000
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select name='mode' class='mode'>
            <option value='1'></option>
            <option value='2'>View</option>
            <option value='3'>Additional</option>
            <option value='4'>Test</option>
            <option value='5'>Support</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            306,939,000
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="View">
        <td>
            <b>View</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            306,939,000
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Additional">
        <td>
            <b>Additional</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            306,939,000
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Test">
        <td>
            <b>Test</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            306,939,000
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Support">
        <td>
            <b>Support</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            306,939,000
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

SCRIPT:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".View,.Additional,.Test,.Support").css("display", "none");
        $("select.mode").change(function () {
            //$(".View,.Additional,.Test,.Support").css("display", "none");
            $('tr:gt(' + $(this).parent().parent().index() + '):lt(' + parseInt($(this).parent().parent().index() + ($(this).find("option").length - 2)) + ')').css("display", "none");
            $("tr:nth-child(" + ($(this).parent().parent().index() + parseInt($(this).val())) + ")").css("display", "block");
        });
    });
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks this seems to work, but If I select an option for row 1, when I select an option on row 2, row ones option is removed.

Comment: I have updated the answer so as to meet your requirement, hope this would resolve your issue and meet your requirement.

Comment: This does work, but the view option shouldn't show any `tr` I've tried removing the class and entry but that messes up the form. Also the columns don't seem to line up on the table ?